# Converting Timestamp Text to Date Format using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following type of Timestamp in a CSV File with several thousand lines:

```
Oct 1, 2014 - 06:22:25
```

Now I know that I can extract the data using formulas, and that I could theoretically do so in VBA as well. However, this seems like a rather messy solution to write out all the `Worksheetapplication` Functions.

Is there a standard function that would allow me to do this?
I was hoping someone can shine a light on this for me?

Comment: The `LEFT` and `DATEVALUE` native worksheet functions are also available as native VBA commands.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question properly, you dont need a vba. You can do it using formula... I have converted your string into date format.

A1 =  `Oct 1, 2014 - 06:22:25`
B1 =  `=TEXT(DATEVALUE(MID(A1,1,FIND("-",A1)-2)),"dd/mm/yy")`

Hope that helps

Comment: I wouldn't convert the datevalue to text - leave it as a date, and then format the cell

Comment: subject says convert to date format. I did not understand that well hence this solution.. What you said can be done... =DATEVALUE(MID(A1,1,FIND("-",A1)-2)) and then format the cell however OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

2 simple ways to do this.
In both cases, MS will easily convert your string date to a true as long as you get rid of the hyphen.
Both of these solutions have embedded formulas/functions.

**Formula:**

```
=REPLACE(A1,FIND("-",A1),1,"")
```

**VBA:**

```
Function GetDate(sDate As String) As Date
    GetDate = CDate(Replace(sDate, "-", ""))
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this solution doesn't work for me because my Excel version is not an english one. Thus Excel doesn't automatically recognice the date format. DATEVALUE gives me an error. This problem also pops up if I try to do it via Formula.

Comment: The sample you gave looks the same as the US. Do the month abbreviations change? If so, what language is it?